# exponential calculate percentage growth rate

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

Money grows at a steady exponential rate, where the growth is $x$ times the previous day's growth. on 30 June it was \$10 and ten days later it was \$700. what is the percentage growth rate?

I am assuming it is $70=e^r.$
Is that right?

Comment: Do you want the rate per day?

Comment: yes please; i require the rate per day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is incorrect. Let the increase be $R\%$ per day. Using Geometric Progression formulae, we get:
$$700=10\Biggr(1+\frac R{100}\Biggr)^{10}$$ 
$$R=52.936027\%$$

Comment: are you raising the power to the number of days?

Comment: Of course because the amount increases **per day**.

Comment: sorry; one last question. what is the value of r in $?

Comment: @kimmy that changes by the day, that's why percent is easier to use.